# Similar to Lehmar's totient problem

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, totient-function

Find all positive integer such that 
$$\phi(n)^2\mid n^2-1$$

My progress so far:

I proved that $n$ has to be a odd square-free integer. So $n=p_{1}p_{2}\ldots p_{k}$. So the question can be restated as following:
$$\prod (p_{i}-1)^2\mid (p_{1}p_{2}\ldots p_{k})^2-1$$
From here I farther transformed the question as follows (Not sure if this simplifies the problem but it is definitely beautiful):

If $P(x)$ a polynomial such that all it's roots are distinct odd primes, prove that 
$$P(1)^2\nmid P(0)^2-1$$

And now I am stuck. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $n=1,2,3$ are solutions and there is no additional solution upto $n=10^8$

Comment: Still no additional solution upto $n=10^9$

Comment: Has anyone made any progress?